# Is there something like a while switch?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is something that takes in a user input and tests it into preset 'cases' (like a switch) and if there is no 'cases' matching the user input the switch-thing resets (like a while statement). Then it prompts the user for an input and then tests if that matches and if it doesn't it keeps doing this until the input from the user matches one of the cases.  I realize that you can do this with a while/if/else combo and am simply wandering if there is a way to do this with a while statement.

Edit:

What I ended up doing is...

```
String aString = scanner.next();
boolean switchOff = false;

while ( switchOff = false )
{
switch (aString)
{
case "example" : //What I want to happen
switchOff=true;
break;
default: aString = scanner.next();
break;
}
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: I was halfway through a long and detailed answer to this when it was closed.  I was motivated by my belief that the accepted answer is incorrect.  Should I throw my work away now?  OP has described what they have tried and what is expected.  Why would anyone close this?

Comment: @DavidWallace you must be new here... ok you are not.

Comment: I am kind of hoping that some SENSIBLE people will read my comment and click reopen.  I think people are often too trigger-happy with the close link.  The fact that this question has attracted three answers (including my own) indicates that it is not a bad or worthless question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine them with

```
OUTER: while(true) switch(tested) {
    case GOOD:
        // something
        break;
    case ALSO_GOOD:
        // something
        break;
    default:
        break OUTER;
}
```

Comment: Ahh... thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: Though this would work, Is it best practice to use such labels in general ? Your thoughts @Peter

Comment: @Prateek Don't use labels if there is a simpler way of doing something, but in this case I couldn't think of one.

Comment: Doesn't this actually do the reverse of what the OP wants?  It keeps going if one of the cases matches, but breaks out of the outer loop if none of the cases match.  The OP wanted to keep going if none of the cases match, but break out of the loop if one of them did.  I am contemplating a downvote - sorry @Peter.

Comment: @DavidWallace Could you just change the `while(true)` to `while(false)`?

Comment: @Programmer-Lvl1 - You could do that.  If you did, how many times do you think the loop would be iterated?

Answer (score 0):

```
do{ input = askInput(); } while( !match(input) );
```